# How to remove row from result set in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, resultset

Based on some condition I want to be able to remove a row from the result set returned from the `$mysqli` object in php.  Does anyone know how to do that?

```
<?php
... 
    $result_set = $mysqli->query('select * from schema.table1;');

    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
        if (/* some condition */){
            //remove this row from the result set
        }
    }

    $result_set->data_seek(0);
    //now the result set has less rows than it did to begin with
    ....
?>
```

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but couldn't you do this with a WHERE in your query?

Comment: not a silly question but the condition is more complex than that and includes things outside of the database.

Comment: You want to SELECT by Primary Key (for uniqueness) and IF the WHERE conditions are met, then use that variable in the DELETE from schema.table1. Be careful - very dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this to the result set. Your best bet would be to build an array instead.

```
<?php
... 
    $valid_results = array();
    $result_set = $mysqli->query('select * from schema.table1;');

    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
        if (/* some condition */){
            continue;
        }
        $valid_results[] = $row;
    }

    //do stuff with $valid_results
    ....
?>
```